# Link fails to work unless refreshing

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am currently developping a mobile website using JQuery mobile. I am using multiple pages whitin my `foobar.html` to navigate as follow :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
    <script src="jquery-js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <title>Foobar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="foo">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#bar" data-role="button">Go to Bar</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="bar">
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Bar</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I load the `foobar.html` file, click on **Go to Bar** and it works fine ; however, when I navigate from  `index.hmtl` to `foobar.html` and test it again, the link fails to work. Refreshing the page solves the problem.

What would explain this behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

When working with **`jQuery Mobile`** and multiple HTML files it is important to understand that when you go from **`index.html`** to **`foobar.html`** **ONLY** first page will be loaded. Basically jQuery Mobile will strip rest of the page, including **`HEAD`** and rest of the **`BODY`** content.

So when working with several **`HTML`** pages, only first page can have several inner pages, all other **`HTML`** pages can have **ONLY** 1 page. In your case only page **`#foo`** was loaded into the DOM, page **`#bar`** was discarded.

Also, I have another **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** where is described how **`jQuery Mobile`** handles multiple HTML page loading.

## Proof of concept

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <!-- META TAGS Declaration -->
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>TEst</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>              
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>  
            <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#foo', function(){ 
                alert($('#body-test').html());
            });
            </script>           
        </head>

        <body id="body-test">
            <div data-role="page" id="portfolio"  data-add-back-btn="true">             
                <div data-role="content" data-theme='c' >
                    <a href="test.html" data-role="button">Go to Bar</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Page Project #1 -->
        </body>     
</html>
```

#### test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
        <script src="jquery-js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
        <title>Foobar</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="foo">
            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#bar" data-role="button">Go to Bar</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="bar">
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Bar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you run this example it will tell you (alert you) that only page #foo is loaded.

Comment: Thaks, for the neat explanation. So, I guess the cleanest way to solve this problem is to create one html file per **page**?