# j query dose not working with angular 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, refresh

i working with my first project with angular js

i want to use this template  to create admin panel 
https://colorlib.com/polygon/metis/blank.html

and i add  the css and js files also to index.html

i try to use directive to solve the problem
and [JavaScript in jQuery mobile not working unless I refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405013/javascript-in-jquery-mobile-not-working-unless-i-refresh)
but got problem the j query doesn't   working  until i refresh the page ???
any one have idea ??

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [AngularJS's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which contains minimal required jquery functions

Comment: is there any reason make the code work perfect after we  refresh

Comment: i have the solution for this problem .. i move all the file which call the j query  to inside ng-view